# What primitives can expandably tell us about the current horizontal list?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, tex-core

I've been writing some code that expands macros and catches characters and non-expandable primitives as they reach TeX's stomach, and I encountered an issue: since I gather letters one by one, with non-expandable code (at least `\futurelet`), kerning between letters is destroyed, as well as ligatures.  It would thus be better to grab letters until encountering a non-letter typesetting command.  However, my code must cope with things like

```
a b\ifdim\lastskip>0pt hi!\fi c
```

If I typeset `b` before continuing expansion, then the kerning between `b` and `c` is destroyed.  But if I first continue expansion, then `\lastskip` will see the previous space, and not be `0pt` as it should.  My solution is to insert an `\hskip 0pt\relax` when starting the word, then collect letters, performing expansion, then remove the given skip and typeset the letters.  This also ensures that `\lastpenalty` and others are zero, as they should.

To make sure that my solution is correct, I need to know what primitives can access information about what is being typeset.  In TeX, there is at least `\lastkern`, `\lastpenalty` and `\lastskip` (not `\lastbox` since it is not expandable).  What about pdfTeX primitives?  XeTeX primitives (in particular, can information about the last character be obtained)?  LuaTeX is probably another can of worms altogether because everything can be done expandably through `\directlua`: I cannot have any control.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for etex there is `\lastnodetype` which for example expands to 0 and 1 in these examples

```
aaa\the\lastnodetype bbb


aa\hbox{a}\the\lastnodetype bbb

\bye
```

Not sure what information you consider in scope for the question eg `\parshape` and etex's `\parshapelength` etc tell you "something about the current paragraph" but perhaps you do not mean to include that (or if you do then then `\leftskip` and `\rightskip`) Perhaps you mean current horizontal list rather than current paragraph?

Comment: You are right, I meant current horizontal list.  I fixed the title accordingly.  This lastnodetype business will be tricky to replicate.  I guess I'll have to cheat and make `\lastnodetype` into a protected macro somehow.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch I'm not sure quite how your macro is working but if it has already seen the previous tokens you could set lastnotetype "by hand" since you know what the last node was.

Comment: just like `\lastskip`, `\lastnodetype` is read-only.  I need to turn it into a register, but at the same time I don't want to be tracking its value at all times, so I probably need to switch it back and forth between the primitive and a register.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch something like that, yes...